spring boot app not starting with tomcat after upgraded to version 3
I am upgrading my application to spring boot 3 with java17 ,I updated all required configuration as per the change in spring 3 lib in application.yaml but getting a strange issue when trying to deploy.

java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple SSLHostConfig elements were provided for the host name [default]. Host names must be unique.\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.addSslHostConfig(AbstractEndpoint.java:288)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.addSslHostConfig(AbstractEndpoint.java:244)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.addSslHostConfig(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:742)\n\tat

I have below config in application.yaml related to tomcat
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true

what can be the issue here?

Possibly related thread

Do you have any other Tomcat-related configuration in your application, in code for example rather than yaml? A minimal, reproducible example would help here.
